# What determines if a JS 6 script is a module?

Tags: module, ecmascript-6

Normally all global variables and functions in a JS script in a browser are attributes to Window, if I'm right.

With modules that shouldn't be the case. What determines that global vars and funcs do not become attributes to Window? I haven't found a `module` keyword.

I've been reading quite a lot about this, but it seems to be so self-evident that I could not find an explanation.

Comment: UMD vs AMD vs CJS vs ES6-Modules https://auth0.com/blog/javascript-module-systems-showdown/

Comment: *normally all global variables and functions in a JS script in a browser are attributes to Window* this is true only for variables declared using `var` keyword, not using `let` or `const`. And also this is only true if you run the JS in a browser. The global object in a browser is called `window`.

Comment: So how would one define a function that's not an attribute of the global object and also cannot be imported? (so it's local to the module where it's defined)

Comment: In `funcs.js`: `export function duderino() { ... }` - `import { duderino } from "funcs";`

Comment: I don't get your edited comment. You do know that inside a function, you can also define functions using var, let or const, and also by just declaring a named function, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, so your function duderino is exported. But what if I DON'T want to export it and also NOT be globally available. How should I define it then?

Comment: `function myFunc() { function duderino() { ... } }` now `duderino` can only be called inside `myFunc`. Or from where do you want it accessible precisely?

Comment: I see. So export limits visibility, rather than enlarging it. Because if I just leave it out, I'll have a global function that can be called from any other script. I can't make duderino local to the module, enabling it to be called only from within the same module. I have to make it local to a function.

Comment: The answer to your question for ES6 module syntax at least, is "the community hasn't quite decided yet". Some people are starting to use ".mjs" as the file extension for modules, but if they haven't you kind of just have the guess based on if `import` or `export` are used.